# Does this DFA have a solution?

Tags: formal-languages

I trying to create a DFA that can recognize strings with alphabet {a,b,c} where a and c appear a even number of times and where b appears an uneven number of times.

I am wondering that this may only be expressed with other mathods such as turing machine or context-free languages.

You might find it fun to think of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using a DFA simply have a state for each of the combinations of an odd number of a's, b's and c's. So if you're in the state with even # of a's, odd # of b's and an even # of c's then you can accept. You can also define simple transitions for any of the other cases. So naively this can be done with 8 states.

Comment: I tried the same thing you are suggesting before posting the question. I thought it would work but it didn't. I couldn't accept the word "acac". This makes 8 states,not 9.

Comment: That's because "acac" doesn't have an odd number of "b"'s.

Comment: OMGG . I'm stupid. You are right. Let me check my solution. It may have been always right! If so I should delete de question.

Comment: So, what emschorsch suggested is the way to solve this problem everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go about constructing such a machine is as follows.
Make eight states. Each state represents a possible 3 tuple combination. The start state is a state representing the combination where all three are even. If a is the first character in the input, then you would to a state that represents an odd number of a's and even number of b's and c's. The accept state is where a and c are even, and b is odd.

Comment: I did the same before posting. I couldn't accept "acac". The problem is that in the last "c" I am in a state that by taking the "c" path I arrive to a node where i have the (pair,pair,pair) combination.